# Modify script to check for a data-rel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify this script to also check if the anchor tag **does not** contain a data-rel of `prettyPhoto[product-gallery]`.

I have tried a few times to add an `||` to line 3 with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$('a[href*=".jpg"], a[href*=".jpeg"], a[href*=".png"], a[href*=".gif"]').each(function(){
  //single image popup
    if ($(this).parents('.iwmp-gallery').length == 0) { //Line #3
      $(this).magnificPopup({
        type:'image',
          callbacks: {
            open: function() {
             $('.mfp-description').append(this.currItem.el.attr('alt'));
},
                          afterChange: function() {
                            $('.mfp-description').empty().append(this.currItem.el.attr('alt'));
                          }
                        },
                            image: {
                                markup: 
                                '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
                                '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                                '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
                                '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">'+
                                '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
                                '<div class="mfp-description"></div>'+
                                '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '</div>',
                                titleSrc: function(item) {
                                    return item.el.find('img').attr('alt');
                                }                           
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Thanks

Comment: Line 3 is not clear. Can you mark that with a comment?

Comment: Have now marked line 3. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the selector

```
$('a[href*=".jpg"], a[href*=".jpeg"], a[href*=".png"], a[href*=".gif"]')
```

for  `data-rel`

```
$('a[href*=".jpg"][data-rel], a[href*=".jpeg"][data-rel], a[href*=".png"][data-rel], a[href*=".gif"][data-rel]')
```

Or if you need an or condition, you can modify
the if condition to :

```
if (($(this).parents('.iwmp-gallery').length == 0)||$(this).attr("data-rel"))
```

Refer : [Has attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

For not data-rel:

```
$('a[href*=".jpg"]:not([data-rel]), a[href*=".jpeg"]:not([data-rel]), a[href*=".png"]:not([data-rel]), a[href*=".gif"]:not([data-rel]'))
```

and for or condition:

```
if (($(this).parents('.iwmp-gallery').length == 0)||(!$(this).attr("data-rel").length))
```

Comment: Sorry.. I've realised that my query was incorrect and have updated my question above. I want to check that it does not contain a data-rel. Sorry. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was

```
if (($(this).parents('.iwmp-gallery').length == 0)||(!$(this).attr("data-rel").length))
```

Thanks to @KK